# What type of hardwood flooring is this?

Tags: hardwood-floor, laminate-floor, engineered-flooring

I'm trying to determine the type of hardwood flooring i have here.   The pictures below show the edge-on and side-on views.

Is this real hardwood (looks like not), engineered,  laminate,  or something else?

[image: edge-on view]

[image: side-on view]

Comment: Bamboo  I  think    How old is it?

Comment: Looks like engineered hardwood to me, wouldnt be laminate. Laminate is like an MDF core with a printed wood top.

Comment: @Kris it's at least as old as when I bought the house in  2007, and didn't look new then.  I think it's original to the house, which was built in 1982 or so.  Anyway, I'm more interested in the class of build (engineered, solid, laminate, etc) rather than the wood species.

Comment: Looks like old school tongue and groove laminate to me.  1/8" laminate sheet on solid or plywood backer board.  The side shot showing the laminate on multiple separate lathes of backer makes less sense with that theory.  Definitely qualifies as a laminate of some sort as that word just implies multiple adhered layers.

Comment: Looks like thin wood on thicker wood (both "real" as in cut from trees, not ground up and re-processed) from here.